# SciNet and LightTS: What causes temporal discrepancy between predicted and observed values?

Tags: python, pytorch, time-series, prediction

Both SciNet and LightTS are used to predict values {+1, ..., +} from the observed values  = {− +1, ..., −1,  | ∈ R  }, where the data is down-sampled in the temporal direction. After executing both codes and generating predictions and Ytest, a comparison graph was plotted for the observed and predicted values of the test data (with L=1). It should be noted that the input observed values were normalized, resulting in the output values also being within the range of 0 to 1."[Predict and Real data of Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwWPS.png)

It appears that the evaluation metric uses both the observed and predicted values at the same time step, but upon examining the graph, there seems to be a time shift of one unit. In other words, it appears that the predicted values {-L+1, ..., } are being calculated from the observed values  = {−+1, ..., −1,  | ∈ R  }.
I am uncertain whether this is part of the intended specification, a problem with the publicly available code, or if there might be an issue with the way I have generated the outputs 'predict' and 'Ytest'.

Could you please help me determine the cause of this time shift? Is it inherent to the method's design, or should the code be modified to correct it? Alternatively, if my 'predict' and 'Ytest' outputs need adjustments.

```
def validate(self, data, X, Y, evaluate=False):
    self.model.eval()
    total_loss = 0
    total_loss_l1 = 0

    total_loss_mid = 0
    total_loss_l1_mid = 0
    n_samples = 0
    predict = None
    res_mid = None
    test = None

    forecast_set = []
    Mid_set = []
    target_set = []

    if evaluate:
        save_path = os.path.join(self.args.save_path, self.args.model_name)
        self.model = load_model_financial(self.model, save_path, model_name=self.args.dataset_name, args=self.args)[0]

    for X, Y in data.get_batches(X, Y, self.args.batch_size, False):
        with torch.no_grad():
            forecast = self.model(X)
        # only predict the last step
        true = Y[:, -1, :].squeeze()
        output = forecast[:, -1, :].squeeze()

        forecast_set.append(forecast)
        target_set.append(Y)

        if len(forecast.shape) == 1:
            forecast = forecast.unsqueeze(dim=0)

        if predict is None:
            predict = forecast[:, -1, :].squeeze()
            test = Y[:, -1, :].squeeze()  # torch.Size([32, 3, 137])

        else:
            predict = torch.cat((predict, forecast[:, -1, :].squeeze(1)))
            test = torch.cat((test, Y[:, -1, :].squeeze(1)))

        scale = data.scale.expand(output.size(0), data.m)
        bias = data.bias.expand(output.size(0), data.m)

        total_loss += self.evaluateL2(output *
                                      scale + bias, true * scale + bias).item()
        total_loss_l1 += self.evaluateL1(output *
                                         scale + bias, true * scale + bias).item()

        n_samples += (output.size(0) * data.m)

    forecast_Norm = torch.cat(forecast_set, axis=0)
    target_Norm = torch.cat(target_set, axis=0)


    rse = math.sqrt(total_loss / n_samples) / data.rse
    rae = (total_loss_l1 / n_samples) / data.rae

    # only calculate the last step for financial datasets.
    predict = forecast_Norm.cpu().numpy()[:, -1, :]
    Ytest = target_Norm.cpu().numpy()[:, -1, :]
```

The above is a part of the code from "exp_short.py".

The following are the paper and the website for the code:

[SciNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.09305)

[SciNet:code](https://github.com/cure-lab/SCINet)

[LightTS](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.01186)

[LightTS:code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/byz4l6x7ak5o1ye/AAA2QNv86mED8_YCUG8Qmpwsa?dl=0)

I tried setting the horizon to 2 or 3, but I could only output values {-L+1, ..., } from  = {−+1, ..., −1,  | ∈ R  }. I also attempted to adjust the batch processing during input to ensure it was divisible by the batch size, but it did not improve the situation.